# Row details panel

Tags: ag-grid

Is it possible to have row details open on click? like below closed/open state:
[image: closed state]

[image: open state]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Check the documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/) on how you can do this, along with how to custom implement it [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail-custom-detail/).

Comment: i manged to do it by resizing the row dynamically. however the only thing left is either there is an event when row - which is out of view gets redrawn? (so I can remove the custom height)